# Remove surrounding quotes from a Swift String while keeping Inner Quotes similar to Kotlin command string.removeSurrounding

Tags: swift, string, kotlin

I have Swift strings that start and end in double-quotes.  They also contain double-quotes inside.  The inside double-quotes are a pair (1st example) unless the are the last character before the close double-quote (2nd example):

`"-5 -5"" -Animated -Cartoon"` which I need to be `-5 -5" -Animated -Cartoon`

or

`"-POTF -Force -12 -12""` which I need to be `-POTF -Force -12 -12"`

I need a way to remove the outside double-quotes and set the "inner" double-quotes to just one double-quote.
In Kotlin, I can do the following:  use `removeSurrounding` (see following definition) and then replaces 2-double quotes with 1

removeSurrounding

> Removes the given delimiter string from both the start and the end of this string **if and only if it starts with and ends with** the delimiter. Otherwise returns this string unchanged.

```
newString = string.removeSurrounding("\"").replace("\"\"", "\"")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create your own string removeSurrounding method extending StringProtocol, you just need to check if the original string starts and ends with a specific character and return the original dropping the first and last characters otherwise return it unchanged:

```
extension StringProtocol {
    /// Removes the given delimiter string from both the start and the end of this string if and only if it starts with and ends with the delimiter. Otherwise returns this string unchanged.
    func removingSurrounding(_ character: Character) -> SubSequence {
        guard count > 1, first == character, last == character else {
            return self[...]
        }
        return dropFirst().dropLast()
    }
}
```

---

And to create a mutating version of the same method you just need to constrain the extension to RangeReplaceableCollectionn declare your method as mutating and use the mutating methods removeFirst and removeLast instead of dropFirst and dropLast:

```
extension StringProtocol where Self: RangeReplaceableCollection {
    mutating func removeSurrounding(_ character: Character) {
        guard count > 1, first == character, last == character else {
            return
        }
        removeFirst()
        removeLast()
    }
}
```

---

Playground testing:

```
let string1 = #""-5 -5"" -Animated -Cartoon""#
let string2 = #""-POTF -Force -12 -12"""#
let newstring1 = string1.removingSurrounding("\"").replacingOccurrences(of: "\"\"", with: "\"")  // "-5 -5" -Animated -Cartoon"
let newstring2 = string2.removingSurrounding("\"").replacingOccurrences(of: "\"\"", with: "\"") // "-POTF -Force -12 -12""
```

Comment: Works like a charm.  Very efficient.  Thank you.  Not sure why the queston or answer were downvoted without a comment as to why.